# how to replace string values of column values by SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i am working with SQL Server 2012, i need to remove a particular string data from column values this string has saved multiple times for a user into the column.

I need to write the stored procedure for it. My table structure is like following.

```
Id      UserId     ColumnNeedUpdate         Address
1       2565       l:\xyz\sfd\mybook.png    Mumbai
1       2565       l:\xyz\sfd\myook.png     Mumbai
1       2565       l:\xyz\sfd\mbook.png     Mumbai
1       2465       l:\xzd\sfd\mybook.png    Mumbai
1       2265       C:\myz\sfd\mybook.png    Mumbai
1       2965       C:\xsz\sfd\mybook.png    Mumbai
1       2565       l:\xyz\sfd\maybook.png   Mumbai
1       2765       C:\zxu\sfd\mybook.png    Mumbai
1       2465       m:\xdz\sfd\mybook.png    Mumbai
```

Now if i write the select query for the user 2565 the result will be following.

```
1       2565       l:\xyz\sfd\mybook.png    Mumbai
1       2565       l:\xyz\sfd\myook.png     Mumbai
1       2565       l:\xyz\sfd\mbook.png     Mumbai
1       2565       l:\xyz\sfd\maybook.png   Mumbai
```

purpose of writing the stored procedure is to update column "ColumnNeedUpdate" like following.

```
mybook.png, myook.png,mbook.png,maybook.png
```

I am pretty new in sql server stored procedure so I tried following way.

```
Create PROCEDURE UsingExistsstoredprocedure(@Id int)
AS
DECLARE @ResultValue int,@ResultFirstName nvarchar(500),@imax int,@i int;
BEGIN TRAN
IF EXISTS(SELECT Name FROM Image WHERE UserId = @Id)
     BEGIN
        SET @imax=@@ROWCOUNT
        SET @i=1

    WHILE(@i<=@imax)
    BEGIN
        SET @ResultFirstName =(SELECT Name FROM [picsilo].[dbo].[Image] WHERE UserId=@i);
        IF CHARINDEX('\',@ResultFirstName)>0
        SET @ResultFirstName=SUBSTRING(@ResultFirstName,0,CHARINDEX('\',@ResultFirstName))
    INSERT Into Image (Name)VALUES(@ResultFirstName)
    END
 END
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What problems have you faced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE MyTable SET ColumnNeedUpdate = 
    REPLACE(ColumnNeedUpdate, 'l:\xyz\sfd\', '')
WHERE UserId = 2565
```

**Disclaimer:** This code changes the data in your table. Use at your own discretion.

Comment: What if prefixes to remove are not static "l:\xyz\sfd\" string?

Comment: Check out Jérôme's answer, which uses `CHARINDEX` to find the location of the last backslash in the string.

Comment: @Dan thanks for this answer. Helped me answer my own question so I made sure to reference this question. Thanks! I up-voted this.

Answer (score 1):

It should work even with a non static "l:\xyz\sfd\" string :

```
UPDATE MyTable SET ColumnNeedUpdate = 
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ColumnNeedUpdate), 0,
       CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(ColumnNeedUpdate)) - 1))
WHERE UserId = 2565
```

Comment: Remove -1 else it will skip first character

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UsingExistsstoredprocedure(@Id int)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE MyTable SET ColumnNeedUpdate =
        REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ColumnNeedUpdate ), 0, 
          CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(ColumnNeedUpdate )))) 
    FROM MyTable WHERE UserId = @Id 
END
```